# Calculated field not working as expected

Tags: tableau-api

The below mentioned is the calculation field to fetch the prior months.

```
CASE [TimeFrame]
when 'DateMonth' then if [Months between today and Date]=0 then 'show' end
when 'Last2Months' then if [Months between today and Date]>=0 and [Months between today and Date]<=1 then 'show' end
when 'Last3Months' then if [Months between today and Date]>=0 and [Months between today and Date]<=2 then 'show' end
else 'hide'
end
```

The above mentioned Calculation is working as expected for Last2Months and Last3Months but its not showing any result for the current month.

Example if the user selects 11/1/2015 then,

- DateMonth should be November--currently no data is shown...
- Last2Months should be November and October--working as expected
- Last3Months should be November,October and September --working as expected.

Also i need to add up the months as rolling sum and display automatically instead of the drop down selected.

Please find the twbx attached.

Any inputs would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything was attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `IF` statements within your `CASE` statement that do not have an `ELSE` which means you will get some NULLs in certain cases (they will not be caught by the `ELSE` in your `CASE`).

I would rewrite like this. See if this gets you your results:

```
IF [TimeFrame] = 'DateMonth' AND [Months between today and Date] = 0 THEN 'show'
ELSEIF [TimeFrame] = 'Last2Months' AND [Months between today and Date] >= 0 AND [Months between today and Date] <= 1 THEN 'show'
ELSEIF [TimeFrame] = 'Last3Months' AND [Months between today and Date] >= 0 AND [Months between today and Date] <= 2 THEN 'show'
ELSE 'Hide'
END
```

Comment: IF  [Months between today and Date]=0 then '30Days' 
ELSEIF  [Months between today and Date]>=0 and [Months between today and Date]<=1 then '60Days' 
ELSEIF [Months between today and Date]>=0 and [Months between today and Date]<=2 then '90Days' end